# Why does my code work for ActiveChart but not for the chart name?

Tags: vba, excel, charts

At the moment, my code reads:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

' This Macro Code for this sheet updates the x axis range for the graph in 'Dashboard' automatically
Dim V_900_SPC As Worksheet
Set V_900_SPC = Sheets("AR Data 900A SPC")

Dim chart1values As String, chart1_xvalues As String
chart1values = Cells(2, 10)
chart1_xvalues = Cells(3, 10)

V_900_SPC.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='AR Data 900A SPC'!" & chart1values
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='AR Data 900A SPC'!" & chart1_xvalues

Cells(1, 1).Activate


End Sub
```

However if I replace "ActiveChart." with "V_900_SPC.ChartObjects("Chart 1")."  (and obviously delete the line that activates the chart object) then the code doesn't work. What's going on??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
V_900_SPC.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='AR Data 900A SPC'!" & chart1values
```

The reasoning being that `ChartObject` and `Chart` isn't the same thing. `ChartObject` is a container for `Chart`, and `SeriesCollection` belongs to `Chart`.

I recently [made a post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35846158/create-an-average-of-multiple-excel-chart-without-the-data-source/36019602#36019602) that is relevant to this, that also contains more information and examples, as well as MSDN links.

Comment: It works! Thanks Vegard. Follow up question: How is it that when I get intellisense up - by pressing ctrl space - after ChartObjects("Chart 1") there is no "Chart" option to add next? Odd. It's like Chart isn't a known object of ChartObjects

Comment: I can't answer that, unfortunately. I do know that IntelliSense does work correctly if you declare a `ChartObjects` variable, like I did in the example I linked to. If I were to speculate it would be related to how the IDE parses object types on the fly, maybe?